# Checking length of password vault

Tags: python, python-3.x

The updated code for the errors, it now can succesfully check for enters and maximum and minimum valuesThe updated code for the errors, it now can succesfully check for enters and maximum and minimum valuesThe updated code for the errors, it now can succesfully check for enters and maximum and minimum values

````
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print('''Welcome to password Locker, a place where you can 
store all your passwords to easily enter your precious accounts without
hassle.''')
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")



print('''First lets make an account,''')

while True:
    first_name = input('''What is your first name?''')
    if first_name.isdigit():  #isdi
        print("No numbers")
    else:
        print("Eligible")
        break

while True:
        sur_name = input('''What is your surname?''')
        if sur_name.isdigit():  #isdi
            print("No numbers")
        else:
            print("Eligible")
            break

print('''----------------------------------''')
print('''Welcome, {} {} 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than ten characters long'''.format(first_name, sur_name))
while True:
        username = input("")
        if 0 < len(username) < 10:
                print('''Nice, username''')
                break
        elif not username:
            pass

        else:
            print('''Your username should be a maximum of 10 charecters''')
while True:
    locker_password = input('''Now it's time to setup a password for your locker: ''')
    if len(locker_password) > 4 and len(locker_password) < 11:

        print('''{}, is locked in thanks for joining Password Locker'''.format(locker_password))       
    else:
        print("It should be between 4 and 10 charecters long!")```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JnoH.png
````

Comment: Replace that `continue` with a `break` and add a `if username != "":` check.

Comment: @ Aran-Fey  replace it but it still reasks the question instead of saying the messege below ``` else:
            print('''Your username should be a maximum of 10 charecters''')```

Comment: What username did you input?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I inputed one larger than 10 charecters

Comment: I can't reproduce that. The code correctly checks the length of the input. If you've *only* replaced the `continue` with a `break`, it should work. If it doesn't work, you must've messed something up.

Comment: The new code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and `elif` with a condition and modify the `if` condition a little:

```
username = input('''Welcome, {} {} 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than ten characters long
'''.format(first_name, sur_name))
while True:
        username = input()
        if 0 < len(username) < 10:
                print('''Nice, username''')
                break
        elif not username:
            pass

        else:
            print('''Your username should be a maximum of 10 charecters''')
```

Example output:

```
Welcome, Bob Smith 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than ten characters long

Welcome, Bob Smith 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than ten characters long
12133254827258426763589
Your username should be a maximum of 10 charecters
Welcome, Bob Smith 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than ten characters long
abc
Nice, username
```

Comment: hi @U9-Forward, I put your code in it still dosnt print the Your username should be a maximum of 10 charecters could there be a problem with the rest of my code?

Comment: @hobo Can you copy the whole code and try it again?

Comment: I did put the whole code still not showing that messege, just repeating the messege

Comment: @hobo That's strange, it works well for me

Comment: just inutted my whole code hope fully that helps

Comment: @hobo It works perfectly fine for me, are sure you entered a more than 10 character input?

Comment: I put a photo of my output,  and it just asks question again

Comment: @hobo It is there! right under the input!

Comment: Oh yeah I see it does, but how can I make it so It dosnt repeat the first question agian, only prints that it has to be a maximum of 10 charecters

Comment: Move the question out of the loop (with `print`, not `input`) and use an `input()` with no text inside the loop.

Comment: @hobo You mean it won't ask again?

Comment: @ U9-Forward so basically when the user inputs more than 10 chearecters I want it to just print ```print('''Your username should be a maximum of 10 charecters''')``` instead of both the above but and '''Welcome, {} {} 
what would you like your username to be, it should be something 
memorable and no longer than ten characters long'''

Comment: @Aran-Fey that worked thanks,

Comment: @U9-Forward  I think I fixed it ill update the code now

Comment: @hobo Now? edited mine

Comment: @U9-Forward @ Aran-Fey                                                                                    ```elif username != "":
        print("please enter vaild response")
        break```   I aded this so if the person just preses enter but the code completely ignores it